# MVC Custom EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have been experimenting with MVC (started out yesterday) and was wondering if I could create my "custom control".

I have something like the following:

In my view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, "StringTemplate", new {LabelText = "Test" })
```

"Custom View" which is used to render the control

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.StringTemplate

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field, ViewData["LabelText"].ToString())
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Field)
```

ViewModel

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public StringTemplate UserName { get; set; }
}

public class StringTemplate
{
    [Required]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    public StringTemplate()
    {
        Field = String.Empty;
    }

    public StringTemplate(string field)
    {
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is by calling the @Html.EditorFor, makes use of the StringTemplate and passes the value LabelText. How can I read the value "Test" from the View "StringTemplate"? Also, is there a way that I can do the @Html.ValidationMessageFor() inside the "StringTemplate" view?

Would appreciate if there are any tutorials or links that can help me with this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making things harder than they need to be. You don't have to create a custom class for your Editor Template to consume -- just use a string.

So in your model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And your template would look something like this (be sure to name it "String.cshtml"):

```
@model System.String

@Html.LabelFor(model => model, (string)ViewData["LabelText"])
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new {LabelText = "Test" })
```

Regarding ValidationMessageFor, this can be added to your template as well:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
```